# Create a table in postgress on jupyter results in syntax error?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, docker, nosql

I try to create a table in postgress in my jupyter lab!
but there comes this bug!

```
 %%bash

cat <<"EOF" | sudo docker exec -i dbis-postgres-db-1 psql -U postgres

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS satisfaction;
CREATE DATABASE satisfaction;
\c satisfaction;


CREATE TABLE department (
    id_dept SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    dept VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    zip_code INTEGER NOT NULL

);

COPY department 
    
FROM '/home/heyoka/Schreibtisch/master/DE/data-engineering-infrastructure.git/workspace/data/departments.csv'
WITH (
    FORMAT CSV,
    DELIMITER ',',
    HEADER false,
    NULL ''
);

...

EOF
```

This is the error i received now :

ERROR:  could not open file "/home/heyoka/Schreibtisch/master/DE/data-engineering-infrastructure.git/workspace/data/departments.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ".."
LINE 1: ...

Comment: \copy is a command for the psql client, it's not a SQL command. Most likely you need COPY without the \

Comment: Please don't use images to present information that is fundamentally textual (see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)).

Comment: i add the code and did it without \ ! This is what i get now :( Actually this is the local path of the csv file ! 
        ^

Comment: Yes but it is not local to the Postgres server(nor does the server have permissions on the file) which is in the Docker container I presume.

Comment: Since you where using Jupyter to begin with I'm going to use assume you are programming with Python. I would suggest using `psycopg2` in a Python script and use it's [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) to transfer the data.

Comment: but this code was given from my univeristy, i think we should focus on this code so psycopg was used instead psycop2

Comment: i with psycop2 i get the error that the file is not found in the directory !

Comment: i solved it, the correct path was this '/mnt/workspace/departments.csv', but i do not know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this not worked was because starting the docker container resulted in mounting ! The docker container mounted the files in this path '/mnt/workspace'. So the files were all the time there